# how to check if a input is integar or string in tkinter , python?

Tags: python, tkinter, input, tkinter-entry

so if you add a entry to window in Tkinter , user can write numbers , letters and symbols in it. how can i check if the input from entry is number and its not a letter or symbol?

Comment: There are functions on string to check that: `.isnumeric()`, `.isdigit()`.

Answer (score 2):

you could do something like this

```
s = # whatever the user input
s_is_an_int = True

try: 
    int(s)
    s_is_an_int = True
except ValueError:
    s_is_an_int = False
```

hope this helps :))

Comment: ok let me know what happens

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Snippet:

```
def check_user_input(input):
    try:
        # Convert it into integer
        val = int(input)
        print("Input is an integer number. Number = ", val)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            # Convert it into float
            val = float(input)
            print("Input is a float  number. Number = ", val)
        except ValueError:
            print("No.. input is not a number. It's a string")


input1 = input("Enter your Age ")
check_user_input(input1)

input2 = input("Enter any number ")
check_user_input(input2)

input2 = input("Enter the last number ")
check_user_input(input2)
```

Result:

```
Enter your Age 25
Input is an integer number. Number =  25
Enter any number Parsa Ad
No.. input is not a number. It's a string
Enter the last number
```